# simple Shell Script - howto do the same in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql, oracle10g

I have a simple shell script with SQL code which does:

- generate with SQL*Plus (SQL statement) a batch file
- checks if output from SQL*Plus more than 400 lines (if more than 400 lines exit and writes mail to Operations team)
- if less than 400 lines SQL*Plus output, executes the batch file automatically

This script works very well. I wish to write the same script with PL/SQL (without Shell code). Is this possible? Can you provide me the code (I am in process of learning PL/SQL).

Database is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 on Solaris.

```
#!/bin/ksh
. /opt/db/scripts/setpath.sh

generate_batch ()
{
sqlplus -S $DBUSER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID <<EOF > /opt/db/scripts/tools/delete_connection/batchrun/batchrun.$(/bin/date '+%d%m%Y.%Hh')

set echo Off
set term On
set pages 0
set head off
set ver off
set feed off
set trims on
set linesize 20000

WITH data
    AS (SELECT user_id,
               jc_name,
               upd_time,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY upd_time ASC)
                  rk
          FROM user_jc
         WHERE user_id IN (  SELECT user_id
                               FROM user_jc
                              WHERE JC_NAME LIKE 'CFF\_S\_%' ESCAPE '\'
                           GROUP BY user_id
                             HAVING COUNT (user_id) > 1)
               AND JC_NAME LIKE 'CFF\_S\_%' ESCAPE '\')
SELECT    'DISCONNECT ent_user  FROM job_code WITH user_id = "'
   || user_id
   || '", jc_name = "'
   || jc_name
   || '";'
  FROM data
 WHERE rk = 1;

exit
EOF
}

sanity_check ()
{
line_nr=$(wc -l /opt/db/scripts/tools/delete_connection/batchrun/batchrun.$(/bin/date '+%d%m%Y.%Hh') | awk ' { print $1 } ')
if [ $line_nr -gt 400 ]; then
        (cat /opt/db/scripts/tools/delete_connection/mail_body.txt) | mailx -s "Alert: please manually execute /opt/db/scripts/tools/delete_connection/batchrun/batchrun.$DATE" -r test@example.com test2@example.com
        exit 1
        fi
}

run_batch ()
{
/opt/bmchome/bin/ess batchrun -A -i /opt/db/scripts/tools/delete_connection/batchrun/batchrun.$(/bin/date '+%d%m%Y.%Hh')
}

generate_batch && sanity_check && run_batch
```

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL, I'd do it the other way round:

1. Count number of connections that match your query
2. If result > 400 send email
3. Else generate the disconnection statements, probably with `ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION`...

I don't know your requirement of course, but could it be solved with resource profiles to limit user connections?

```
CREATE PROFILE myprofile LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER = 1;
ALTER USER myuser PROFILE myprofile;
```

Comment: the batch has nothing to do with Oracle DB. The DISCONNECT statements are for proprietary BMC application. Can you write full code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `/opt/bmchome/bin/ess` in your script. I don't have experience running external jobs from Oracle, although it seems to be possible with `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.